# Duvida exercicio de xss

Tags: javascript, segurança, xss

Galera queria entender a seguinte lógica de um desafio de xss que estava fazendo

Assim porque quando coloco `<script>alert(1);</script>` não funciona mas quando coloco `</script><script>alert(1);</script>` a mensagem aparece, o porque?

> The code below generates HTML in an unsafe way. Prove it by calling
>   `alert(1)`.
>
> ```
> function escape(s) {   // Warmup.
>
>    return '<script>console.log("'+s+'");</script>';
> }
> ```

Link desafio: http://escape.alf.nu/0/

Comment: `");alert(1)//`

Comment: Porque o que você digita vira uma string para `console.log("")`. Então fecha a string com `"`, fecha o método com `)`, coloca um `;` para o próximo comando, que é o `alert` e depois comenta o restante com `//` para não dar erro de script

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: @GabrielS. Pode ser até `");alert("Done!` e ainda aproveita as aspas do final :)

Answer (score 1):

Dentro dessa função tens uma string de HTML.

Essa string tem a tag de abertura `<script>` e vai receber conteúdo que o utilizador insere.

Se dentro do conteúdo que inseres colocares a tag de fecho desse script `</script>` então vais "enganar o código" e podes juntar uma nova tag de abertura `<script>` e colocares o que quiseres nela.

No teu primeiro exemplo `<script>alert(1);</script>` [o resultado é](https://jsfiddle.net/zdd7k8dh/):

```
return '<script>console.log("<script>alert(1);</script>");</script>';
```

onde o último `</script>` é descartado pelo browser.

No teu segundo exemplo, interrompes a sintaxe do console.log e geras HTML com a tag script que tu inseriste [e fica assim](https://jsfiddle.net/zdd7k8dh/1/):

```
<script>console.log("</script><script>alert(1);</script>");</script>
```

o primeiro bloco `<script>console.log("</script>` dá erro de sintaxe, mas o browser corre na mesma o proximo bloco `<script>alert(1);</script>` que dá o alert.